# Vim doesn't find jedi, even though it's right there!

Tags: plugin-vundle, plugin-jedi-vim

I have installed jedi-vim using Vundle, adding this line to my `.vimrc` and running `:PluginInstall`.

```
Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
```

The [jedi-vim docs](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim#installation) say I can install jedi using `git submodule update --init` from within the `jedi-vim` git repo. I've tried that and exits right away (maybe Vundle took care of the submodule for me).

In `.vim/bundle/jedi-vim` I have a `jedi` directory and a `jedi_vim.py` file. I can load `python3` and `import jedi` from that directory with no problem.

I've also tried installing jedi with `pip3 install jedi` and `apt-get install python3-jedi`.

`vim --version` shows `-python` and `+python3`.

No matter what I do, when I open a python file, Vim says:

```
Please install Jedi if you want to use jedi-vim.
```

Hey `Vim`, I've installed it three different ways! What's going on?

Comment: [This seems to be a common problem](https://youtu.be/DIzAaY2Jm-s?t=194)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker that's a good one

Comment: I'm going to assume that you are using Python 3.  Can you check that vim is using Python 3 and not 2?

Comment: @Sardathrion, you mean by looking at `vim --version`?

Comment: The code which causes this error in `jedi_vim.py` is fairly straightforward: `try: import jedi except ImportError: no_jedi_warning()` ... Perhaps your `sys.path` is incorrect? Using `:py print(sys.path)` on my systems reveals that it includes `'/home/martin/.vim/plugged/jedi-vim'` and `'_vim_path_'`... I would guess the first one is required for vim-jedi to work (?) It seems the jedi path is added in `initialize.py`.

Comment: You mentioned you installed jedi system-wide. What happens if you type `import jedi` in the Python commandline? If this also fails, it would suggest you have some sort of generic Python problem (strange `PYTHONPATH`?)

Comment: I mean are you *sure* that vim uses Python3? `:python import sys; print(sys.version)` should tell you.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, the comment that you originally had, about checking `sys.path` from within vim revealed that it was using a version of python I had installed from source (and completely forgot about). I removed the source python installation and recompiled vim, and now everything is butter. Thanks!

Comment: @drs Ah, okay. I figured that comment was mistaken, so I removed it; but apparently I was mistaken about being mistaken ;-) I undeleted the comment. In any case, you should add your solution as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had a compiled version of python in `/usr/local` that I had completely forgotten about, and vim was compiled against that one. I verified this by using `:py print(sys.path)`, which showed directories under `/usr/local`. I removed the compiled version of python and recompiled vim against the standard version, and all is well.